# How to plot this spectrogram from my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe about `trajectory`, `segment` and the `prediction` results for an instance of such segment.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'trajectory': [101,102,102,102,102,102,102,102,104,104,104,104,104,104,104,107,107,107,107,
          107,107,107,107,107,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,109,109,109,109,109,109,112,
         112,112,112,112,113,113,113,113,114,114,114,114],
 'segment': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,
          2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2],
  'prediction': [3,0,0,1,3,3,2,2,0,0,4,4,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,
          1,1,0,1,2,1,3,3,3,1,1,4,4,2,1,4,4,3,0,3,3,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head(10)

 trajectory segment prediction
0   101       1       3
1   102       1       0
2   102       1       0
3   102       1       1
4   102       2       3
5   102       2       3
6   102       3       2
7   102       3       2
8   104       1       0
9   104       1       0
```

Now I want to produce a spectrogram of this data, plotting `trajectory` on the `y-axis`, and `segment` on the `x-axis`. In the following way.

- where there are multiple rows for a `trajectory` (almost all), select only 1 row (unique `segment`) for that `trajectory`.
- the corresponding `prediction` value of that row should be the majority value from the predictions of that `segment`.
- attribute colour code to each prediction label (e.g. `0: blue`, `1: red` etc..

Note: the trajectories do not have equal number of segments in all cases, depending on the length of the `trajectory`.

So in the given example, we should first resolve to a new dataframe `df_new` with the following entries:

```
df_new
  trajectory segment  prediction
0    101         1      3
1    102         1      0
2    102         2      3
3    102         3      2
4    104         1      0
5    104         2      4
6    104         3      0
7    107         1      0
8    107         2      2
9    107         3      0
10   108         1      0
11   108         2      1
12   109         1      1
13   109         2      3
14   112         1      1
15   113         2      4
16   113         3      4
17   114         1      0
18   114         2      3
```

**Expected output:**

The expected spectrogram plot from this `MWE` is the figure below:

[image]

How to I achieve the target plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things you're asking in this question. I'm just gonna post the code, you can play with it and modify the plot to your liking:

```
# calculate the data to plot
plot_data = (df.value_counts()
   .sort_values(ascending=False)
   .reset_index()
   .drop_duplicates(['trajectory', 'segment'])
   .pivot_table(index='trajectory', columns='segment', values='prediction', fill_value=0))

# create a discrete color map
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(['w', 'b', 'g', 'y','m'])
bounds = [-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
norm = mcolors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

# plot the data with the color map
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
sns.heatmap(plot_data,
            vmin=-0.5, vmax=4.5,
            cmap=cmap, annot=True)
```

Output:

[image]